# Where is located “using System” in my computer

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

If i have in my .cs code something like that

```
using System ;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
```

And i want find this stuffs in some computer folder. Are there in some directories located or no?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They refer to namespaces, not file locations.
Namespaces are used to organise different classes and to make it easy to avoid conflicting names. The `using` directive just means you can see what namespaces are used and not need to fully qualify the namespace name of any class you use. For instance, if you didn't have `using System;`, then you would need to use `System.String` instead of just `String`. But you can still use the `string` (lowercase 's') keyword.